# Как правильно хранить массив координат в бд, подключенной к yii2?

Tags: база-данных, веб-программирование, yii2, yii, webview

Есть yii2 приложение(страница), содержит графики, которые рисуются по массиву координат.
Массив представляет из себя длинную числовую выборку (x,y).
пример:

```
22,43
32,53
26,43
65,101
23,65
123,56
...
```

Как правильно хранить эти координаты в базе данных?
Пока как вариант рассматриваю текст, который при использовании буду преобразовывать в данные, но может есть более уместные варианты?

структура таблицы бд:

```
graphTable
--------------
id:int
date:datetime
data1:???
data2:???
```

Я пытаюсь понять, какой тип данных использовать для data1 и data2.

Comment: в postgres есть PostGIS  для работы с географическими координатами и есть тип point для задания точек .

Comment: а так, зависит от того, какая СУБД используется

Comment: в качестве субд использую mysql

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте хранил бы в текстовом поле - `json` со всеми координатами